Convexity of the purity of log-concave distributions
I am confused about how to apply some of the properties of log-concave probability distributions. I ran into this confusion as I was trying to prove that the purity (the sum of the squares of the probabilities) of a binomial distribution is convex in the success probability parameter $p$, but somehow ended up proving it was log-concave (demonstrably false) by misapplying some properties of log-concavity and I'm hoping someone here can point out the flaw in my logic.
Consider a probability distribution $P(x | \theta)$ that is log-concave in both $x$ and some parameter $\theta$. The purity of this distribution is $\rho(\theta) = \int P(x|\theta)^2 dx$. The square of a log-concave function is log-concave, so $P(x|\theta)^2$ is log-concave. The marginal of a log-concave distribution is also log-concave. I can't apply this fact directly to $P(x|\theta)$, since $\theta$ is a parameter, not an outcome variable, but it seems that I should still be able to apply the Prékopa–Leindler inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9kopa%E2%80%93Leindler_inequality. This inequality states that if three functions $f, g, h$ obey
$$h((1-\lambda) x + \lambda y) \geq f(x)^{1-\lambda}g(y)^\lambda$$
for $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$, then
$$\int h(x) dx \geq \left (\int f(x) dx \right )^{1-\lambda} \left ( \int g(x) dx  \right )^\lambda$$.
Setting $f(x) = P(x|\theta_1)^2, g(x) = P(x|\theta_2)^2, h(x) = P(x|(1-\lambda)\theta_1 + \lambda \theta_2)^2$, the inequality seems to show that
$$\rho((1-\lambda) \theta_1 + \lambda \theta_2) \geq \rho(\theta_1)^{1-\lambda} \rho(\theta_2)^\lambda$$
That is, it seems to show that $\rho(\theta)$ is log-concave, but I know this to be false because the purity of the binomial distribution is convex in the success probability parameter.
If I had to guess, I'd say the flaw might have something to do with whether or not the distribution $P(x|\theta)$ is jointly log-concave in $x$ and $\theta$, but I don't immediately see where that comes in to the logic I presented above.
Thanks in advance for the explanation!
PS: metaphorical bonus points for anyone that can provide a correct proof that the purity of the binomial distribution is convex in $p$.
